# Docker won't get USER variable set if I use useradd

Tags: command-line, bash, docker

I have a dockerfile with these commands:

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash dev
USER dev

WORKDIR /home/dev/orwell/gtk/build/desktoplinux

ENTRYPOINT "/bin/bash"
```

I need a docker image that has an user, because I have an app that calls https://linux.die.net/man/3/getlogin_r, which requires an user.

However, this system call fails, and I suspect it's because there's no `$USER` variable set inside my docker image, even though I created an user.

Where is the problem?